# Android : Getting Clipboard Data Item List

Tags: android

I want to get all the Clipboard Data Items on the device. By the following code, I can get only the recent Clipboard data.

```
myClipboard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);    
ClipData abc = myClipboard.getPrimaryClip();
ClipData.Item item = abc.getItemAt(0);
String text = item.getText().toString();
```

How can I get complete list of saved Clipborad Data as we see on the device?

Answer (score 2):

Use `getItemCount()` method to obtain the number of items.

Then use the `getItemAt()` method to fetch the items one by one using a loop.

Example:

```
int n = abc.getItemCount();
for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
{
    ClipData.Item item = abc.getItemAt(i);
    String text = item.getText().toString();
}
```

This usually works well with DragEvent.

Comment: Hey Thank you for reply but by "ClipData abc = myClipboard.getPrimaryClip();" we only get current single clipboard data

Comment: @androdevlop Sorry about that. I completely forgot about that. The clipboard holds only one ClipData at a time. The example that I gave usually works well for DragEvent. I recently used it that's why it I gave the example but completely forgot about the clipboard's limitation.

Comment: @androdevlop I think since you have figured out the answer, you should answer your own question and close it.